# script/plugin install for rails 4 (daemon generator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and am trying to get up and running with the daemons gem by following railcasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon. I am using linux Mint 17 and my Gemfile looks like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'feedjira'
```

However when I run `script/plugin install git://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator.git` I get the following error:

```
bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory
```

When I try `rails plugin install git://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator.git` I just get the usage manual.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails::Plugin is deprecated and has been removed since Rails 4.0. Instead of adding plugins to vendor/plugins use gems or bundler with path or git dependencies.

Also if your goal is to run logic in the background there are way newer options to implement like Resque https://github.com/resque/resque or Sidekick https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq